# Proof convex polyhedron with line does not contain a corner if closed

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, discrete-mathematics, optimization

The excercise I am struggling with is the following: Given a convex closed polyhedron that contains a line, the question is, whether this polyhedron can also contain a corner.

My idea was to make a contradiction by constructing somehow a sequence that has its limit in this polyhedron and results in a convex combination of the corner, which would result in a contradiction, but I am not successful showing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ be your polyhedron, and  $L$ be a line contained in it. For any point $p\in P$ consider the closure of the convex hull of $\{p\}\cup L$ and conclude that it contains the line through $p$ parallel to $L$. After further reflection, conclude that $P$ has the product structure $P=L\times Q$ where $Q$ is a convex polyhedron in the orthogonal complement of $L$.

There is nothing special about $Q$, since for any convex polyhedron $Q$ the product $L\times Q$ meets the assumptions of the problem.

Having this product structure, you can draw your conclusions about the "corners" of $P$, whatever a "corner" means.